# Не могу понять смысл спряжений, расскажите об этом подробнее

Tags: спряжение

Я знаю, что спряжение — изменение по числу, лицу. Но для чего нужно это спряжение (кроме случаев на -е, -у, -ю в 1-м спряжении и т. п.) и как образовывать инфинитив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотя эта тема многим кажется ясной и понятной, у меня всё-таки сложилось впечатление, что понимается она как-то механически, на уровне подсознания. Отчасти это связано с тем, что в школе не изучается информация о том, что спряжение глагола в общем случае зависит от основы, что словоизменительная система глагола в русском языке сложная и  включает различные  классы и группы глаголов, каждый из которых относится к 1-му или 2-му спряжению. Мы же не задаем глаголу спряжение, а определяем его ПО ЭМПИРИЧЕСКОМУ ПРАВИЛУ, если личные окончания являются безударными.  **Поэтому заданный вопрос очень полезен и говорит о том, что есть люди, стремящиеся  уяснить для себя эту тему до конца.**

Краткая инструкция

1) Начальная форма глагола называется инфинитивом или неопределенной формой глагола.  Глаголы бывают НЕПРОИЗВОДНЫЕ (видеть, говорить, идти) и ПРОИЗВОДНЫЕ  (обед – обедать).

2) Правильное написание инфинитива  в общем случае проверяется по СЛОВАРЮ,  но также существуют ЭМПИРИЧЕСКИЕ ПРАВИЛА определения безударных суффиксов . Например, суффикс Я пишется, если в основе глагола присутствуют звуки ЭЙ, АЙ, УЙ: таять, отчаяться, веять, сеять, надеяться, чуять.

3) Правильный выбор безударного глагольного  суффикса  имеет принципиальное значение, так как он определяет правописание всех остальных глагольных форм – выбор личных окончаний глаголов, а также суффиксов причастий и деепричастий

4)  Изменение глагола по лицам и числам называется СПРЯЖЕНИЕМ.  Спрягаются только глаголы в изъявительном наклонении в настоящем и будущем времени, например: я знаю, ты знаешь, он знает, я узнаю, ты узнаешь.

5)  Личные формы глаголов настоящего и будущего времени образуются с помощью личных окончаний, выражающих грамматическое значение лица и числа, соответственно получается НАБОР ИЗ ШЕСТИ ОКОНЧАНИЙ (3 лица и 2 числа).  Глаголы в русском языке ИМЕЮТ ДВА СПРЯЖЕНИЯ (ДВА НАБОРА ОКОНЧАНИЙ).

6)  Набор личных окончаний глаголов двух спряжений  определяем  по спряжению глаголов с ударным окончанием.
несу – несёшь – несёт – несём – несёте – несут,  пою – поёшь – поёт – поём – поёте – поют - набор окончаний 1-ого спряжения У/Ю, ЕШЬ, ЕТ, ЕМ, ЕТЕ, УТ/ЮТ.
   молчу – молчишь – молчит – молчим – молчите – молчат;  говорю – говоришь – говорит – говорим – говорите – говорят – набор  окончаний глаголов 2-ого спряжения У/Ю, ИШЬ, ИТ, ИМ, ИТЕ, АТ/ЯТ.

7) Глаголы с УДАРНЫМ окончанием выбирают себе спряжение сами (шить – шьёшь, окончание ЁШЬ, 1 спр).  Если личные окончания являются безударными, то приходится определять спряжение глагола по условному правилу.

8) Спряжение глагола определяется ПО ГЛАГОЛЬНОМУ СУФФИКСУ в том случае, если его личные окончания являются безударными.  Безударный глагольный суффикс также  надо предварительно ПРОВЕРИТЬ.

9) ПРАВИЛО
Все глаголы на ИТЬ относятся ко 2-ому спряжению: бросить,  строить, клеить. 
Все остальные глаголы (на АТЬ/ЯТЬ, ОТЬ, УТЬ, ЕТЬ) относятся к 1-ому спряжению: бегать, шептать, стонать, резать, таять, веять, реять, колоть, полоть, тронуть, кинуть.
Глаголы-исключения 1-ого спряжения:   брить, стелить, а также два редко встречающихся глагола зыбиться, зиждиться. Глаголы-исключения 2-ого спряжения (11 глаголов):  гнать, держать, слышать, дышать  – 4 глагола на АТЬ; видеть, обидеть, ненавидеть, зависеть, смотреть, вертеть, терпеть – 7 глаголов на ЕТЬ.

Answer (score 0):

Спряжение для того и нужно, чтобы правильно уметь писать безударные личные окончания глаголов. 
Напр.: вид....им, дела..ем. Чтобы правильно написать безударную гласную, надо узнать, к какому спряжению относятся эти глаголы. Спряжение ( для глаголов с безударными личными окончаниями) узнается по инфинитиву.